# Partitions reassignment is failing in Kafka 1.1.0

Tags: apache-kafka

Generated `reassignment.json`

```
/home/ubuntu/deploy/kafka/bin/kafka-reassign-partitions.sh --zookeeper 127.0.0.1:2181 --generate --topics-to-move-json-file /home/ubuntu/deploy/kafka/topics_to_move.json --broker-list '<broker-list>' |tail -1 > /home/ubuntu/deploy/kafka/reassignment.json
```

Perform the reassignment

```
/home/ubuntu/deploy/kafka/bin/kafka-reassign-partitions.sh --zookeeper 127.0.0.1:2181 --execute --reassignment-json-file /home/ubuntu/deploy/kafka/reassignment.json
```

I altered a topic like below in kafka 1.1.0

```
/home/ubuntu/deploy/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper 127.0.0.1:2181 --alter --topic Topic3 --config min.insync.replicas=2
```

But whenever I am trying to verify the reassignment like below

```
/home/ubuntu/deploy/kafka/bin/kafka-reassign-partitions.sh --zookeeper 127.0.0.1:2181 --reassignment-json-file /home/ubuntu/deploy/kafka/reassignment.json --verify
```

It is showing the below exception

```
Partitions reassignment failed due to Size of replicas list Vector(3, 0, 2) is different from size of log dirs list Vector(any) for partition Topic3-7
kafka.common.AdminCommandFailedException: Size of replicas list Vector(3, 0, 2) is different from size of log dirs list Vector(any) for partition Topic3-7
    at kafka.admin.ReassignPartitionsCommand$$anonfun$parsePartitionReassignmentData$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(ReassignPartitionsCommand.scala:262)
    at kafka.admin.ReassignPartitionsCommand$$anonfun$parsePartitionReassignmentData$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(ReassignPartitionsCommand.scala:251)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at kafka.admin.ReassignPartitionsCommand$$anonfun$parsePartitionReassignmentData$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(ReassignPartitionsCommand.scala:251)
    at kafka.admin.ReassignPartitionsCommand$$anonfun$parsePartitionReassignmentData$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(ReassignPartitionsCommand.scala:250)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at kafka.admin.ReassignPartitionsCommand$$anonfun$parsePartitionReassignmentData$1.apply(ReassignPartitionsCommand.scala:250)
    at kafka.admin.ReassignPartitionsCommand$$anonfun$parsePartitionReassignmentData$1.apply(ReassignPartitionsCommand.scala:249)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at kafka.admin.ReassignPartitionsCommand$.parsePartitionReassignmentData(ReassignPartitionsCommand.scala:249)
    at kafka.admin.ReassignPartitionsCommand$.verifyAssignment(ReassignPartitionsCommand.scala:90)
    at kafka.admin.ReassignPartitionsCommand$.verifyAssignment(ReassignPartitionsCommand.scala:84)
    at kafka.admin.ReassignPartitionsCommand$.main(ReassignPartitionsCommand.scala:58)
    at kafka.admin.ReassignPartitionsCommand.main(ReassignPartitionsCommand.scala)
```

My server.properties from a broker looks like below

```
############################# Server Basics #############################

# The id of the broker. This must be set to a unique integer for each broker.
broker.id=0

############################# Socket Server Settings #############################

# The port the socket server listens on
port=9092

# Hostname the broker will bind to. If not set, the server will bind to all interfaces
#host.name=localhost

# Hostname the broker will advertise to producers and consumers. If not set, it uses the
# value for "host.name" if configured.  Otherwise, it will use the value returned from
# java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName().
#advertised.host.name=<hostname routable by clients>

# The port to publish to ZooKeeper for clients to use. If this is not set,
# it will publish the same port that the broker binds to.
#advertised.port=<port accessible by clients>

# The number of threads handling network requests
num.network.threads=3

# The number of threads doing disk I/O
num.io.threads=8

# The send buffer (SO_SNDBUF) used by the socket server
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400

# The receive buffer (SO_RCVBUF) used by the socket server
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400

# The maximum size of a request that the socket server will accept (protection against OOM)
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600


############################# Log Basics #############################

log.dirs=/var/lib/kafka/kafka-logs

# The default number of log partitions per topic. More partitions allow greater
# parallelism for consumption, but this will also result in more files across
# the brokers.

# The number of threads per data directory to be used for log recovery at startup and flushing at shutdown.
# This value is recommended to be increased for installations with data dirs located in RAID array.
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1

############################# Log Flush Policy #############################

# Messages are immediately written to the filesystem but by default we only fsync() to sync
# the OS cache lazily. The following configurations control the flush of data to disk. 
# There are a few important trade-offs here:
#    1. Durability: Unflushed data may be lost if you are not using replication.
#    2. Latency: Very large flush intervals may lead to latency spikes when the flush does occur as there will be a lot of data to flush.
#    3. Throughput: The flush is generally the most expensive operation, and a small flush interval may lead to exceessive seeks. 
# The settings below allow one to configure the flush policy to flush data after a period of time or
# every N messages (or both). This can be done globally and overridden on a per-topic basis.

# The number of messages to accept before forcing a flush of data to disk
#log.flush.interval.messages=10000

# The maximum amount of time a message can sit in a log before we force a flush
#log.flush.interval.ms=1000

############################# Log Retention Policy #############################

# The following configurations control the disposal of log segments. The policy can
# be set to delete segments after a period of time, or after a given size has accumulated.
# A segment will be deleted whenever *either* of these criteria are met. Deletion always happens
# from the end of the log.

# The minimum age of a log file to be eligible for deletion
log.retention.hours=36

# A size-based retention policy for logs. Segments are pruned from the log as long as the remaining
# segments don't drop below log.retention.bytes.
log.retention.bytes=1073741824

# The maximum size of a log segment file. When this size is reached a new log segment will be created.
log.segment.bytes=536870912

# The interval at which log segments are checked to see if they can be deleted according 
# to the retention policies
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000

# By default the log cleaner is disabled and the log retention policy will default to just delete segments after their retention expires.
# If log.cleaner.enable=true is set the cleaner will be enabled and individual logs can then be marked for log compaction.
log.cleaner.enable=false

############################# Zookeeper #############################

# Zookeeper connection string (see zookeeper docs for details).
# This is a comma separated host:port pairs, each corresponding to a zk
# server. e.g. "127.0.0.1:3000,127.0.0.1:3001,127.0.0.1:3002".
# You can also append an optional chroot string to the urls to specify the
# root directory for all kafka znodes.
zookeeper.connect=platform1:2181,platform2:2181,platform3:2181

message.max.bytes=15000000
replica.fetch.max.bytes=15000000

auto.create.topics.enable=true

# Timeout in ms for connecting to zookeeper
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000

// Indicates whether to enable replicas not in the ISR set to be elected as leader as a last resort, even though doing so may result in data loss
unclean.leader.election.enable=false

// Disable Topic Deletion
delete.topic.enable=false

############################# Internal Topic Settings  #############################
# The replication factor for the group metadata internal topics “__consumer_offsets” and “__transaction_state”
# For anything other than development testing, a value greater than 1 is recommended for to ensure availability such as 3.
# Currently These properties are not used as we do not use these topic.
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.min.isr=1
```

`reassignment.json`

```
"version": 1, "partitions": [{"topic": "Topic3", "partition": 7, "log_dirs": ["any"], "replicas": [3, 0, 2]}, {"topic": "Topic3", "partition": 4, "log_dirs": ["any"], "replicas": [3, 0, 2]}, {"topic": "Topic3", "partition": 15, "log_dirs": ["any"], "replicas": [2, 3, 0]}, {"topic": "Topic3", "partition": 9, "log_dirs": ["any"], "replicas": [2, 3, 0]}, {"topic": "Topic3", "partition": 12, "log_dirs": ["any"], "replicas": [2, 3, 0]}, {"topic": "Topic3", "partition": 1, "log_dirs": ["any"], "replicas": [3, 2, 0]}, {"topic": "CatchAllTopic", "partition": 0, "log_dirs": ["any"], "replicas": [0, 3, 2]}, {"topic": "Topic3", "partition": 17, "log_dirs": ["any"], "replicas": [0, 3, 2]}, {"topic": "Topic3", "partition": 6, "log_dirs": ["any"], "replicas": [2, 0, 3]}, {"topic": "Topic3", "partition": 3, "log_dirs": ["any"], "replicas": [2, 0, 3]}, {"topic": "Topic3", "partition": 14, "log_dirs": ["any"], "replicas": [0, 2, 3]}, {"topic": "Topic3", "partition": 0, "log_dirs": ["any"], "replicas": [2, 0, 3]}, {"topic": "Topic3", "partition": 11, "log_dirs": ["any"], "replicas": [0, 2, 3]}, {"topic": "Topic3", "partition": 16, "log_dirs": ["any"], "replicas": [3, 0, 2]}, {"topic": "Topic3", "partition": 8, "log_dirs": ["any"], "replicas": [0, 3, 2]}, {"topic": "Topic3", "partition": 2, "log_dirs": ["any"], "replicas": [0, 3, 2]}, {"topic": "Topic3", "partition": 13, "log_dirs": ["any"], "replicas": [3, 0, 2]}, {"topic": "Topic3", "partition": 5, "log_dirs": ["any"], "replicas": [0, 3, 2]}, {"topic": "Topic3", "partition": 10, "log_dirs": ["any"], "replicas": [3, 0, 2]}]}
```

The same flow used to work fine in Kafka 0.10. Can someone let me know what is going wrong? Is anything related to this changed in Kafka 1.1.0?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why don't you try removing all `"log_dirs": ["any"]` from your json file. This "log_dirs" is optional.

Also if you want to keep the log_dirs field try following below format. Your log_dir count should be same as the replicas.

`{"partitions":
       [{"topic": "foo",
         "partition": 1,
          "replicas": [1,2,3],
          "log_dirs": ["any","any","any"]
       }],
  "version":1
 }`

Comment: Can you also let me know what does `log_dirs` field denote here ?

Comment: You may find your answer here - https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Replication+tools#Replicationtools-4.ReassignPartitionsTool